# Can't run AngularJS inside Angular 8 using ngUpgrade

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng-upgrade

I'm trying to run Hybrid Angular application using [ngUpgrade from documentation](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade). The problem is that no matter what I'll do AngularJS is just not raising.

When I put Angular and AngularJS together then both application runs.

```
<body>
    <app-root><app-root>
    <div ng-app="app"></div>
</body>
```

but of course this is wrong, Angular should bootstrap AngularJS, so I changed it to:

```
<body>
    <app-root>
         <div id="ng-app"></div>
    <app-root>     
</body>
```

And in Angular Module I added:

```
export class AppModule {
    constructor(private upgrade: UpgradeModule) { }
    ngDoBootstrap() {
      this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.getElementById('ng-app'), ['app']);
    }
}
```

But still nothing, I have no idea even how I can investiage it and where the problem may be.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found issue, I had declared `bootstrap` inside @NgModule({...})